# Is partialUpdate possible in Kotlin, Android?

Tags: kotlin

I have a method like:

```
update(id, boolean, boolean, boolean)
```

Is it possible to update only id and first boolean and the rest assign to keep the value?
I know I could make another call to have only two necessery method like update(id, boolean)

i.e.

```
update(4, true, (keep), (keep))
```

Comment: "and the rest assign to keep the value." What is _the_ value? A hard-coded [default argument](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#default-arguments)? Or the current value of a property of some underlying object (in which case you may consider using a [scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) rather than a method)?

Comment: This is the method which update room database, but depends on situation the value of third boolean could be false or true I do not want to change it Just change the first boolean. I just want to keep the value of the rest booleans in database not override it.

Comment: How are you updating the database? Through an ORM, or by dynamically building up a SQL statement? In the latter case, it makes more sense to use a [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). If possible, please share (relevant parts of) method `update`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data class, you can use `copy` to get a new instance with the same properties except those given as arguments.

```kotlin
val myDataClass = MyDataClass(id = 2, firstBool = false, secondBool = false, thridBool = false)
val copy = myDataClass.copy(id = 4, firstBool = true)

print(copy.id) // 4
print(copy.firstBool) // true
print(copy.secondBool) // false
print(copy.thirdBool) // false
```

I don't know if you can have a data class in your context though.

Comment: Yes, it is data class. I update room table.

Anyway it's nice idea.